# How to get the individual value from a list of multiple objects using Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7

I have a 4 set of objects listed as below, I need to take the name "sample 4" from the second set of objects (Id: 2). How can I get this value using javascript /angular.

```js
{Id: 1, name: sample 1, code: "type", order: 1}
{Id: 1, name: sample 2, code: "type1", order: 2}
{Id: 1, name: sample 3, code: "type2", order: 3}

{Id: 2, name: sample 1, code: "type", order: 1}
{Id: 2, name: sample 2, code: "type1", order: 2}
{Id: 2, name: sample 3, code: "type2", order: 3}
{Id: 2, name: sample 4, code: "type3", order: 4}

{Id: 3, name: sample 1, code: "type", order: 1}
{Id: 3, name: sample 2, code: "type1", order: 2}
{Id: 3, name: sample 3, code: "type2", order: 3}

{Id: 4, name: sample 1, code: "type", order: 1}
{Id: 4, name: sample 2, code: "type1", order: 2}
{Id: 4, name: sample 3, code: "type2", order: 3}
```

Comment: is it an array of object ?

Comment: yes. Its an array of objects

Answer (score 1):

Use array filter with condition where id is 2 and name is 'sample 4'. This will return another array. You can then retrieve the value from it

```js
let data = [{
    Id: 1,
    name: 'sample 1',
    code: "type",
    order: 1
  },
  {
    Id: 1,
    name: 'sample 2',
    code: "type1",
    order: 2
  },
  {
    Id: 1,
    name: 'sample 3',
    code: "type2",
    order: 3
  },

  {
    Id: 2,
    name: 'sample 1',
    code: "type",
    order: 1
  },
  {
    Id: 2,
    name: 'sample 2',
    code: "type1",
    order: 2
  },
  {
    Id: 2,
    name: 'sample 3',
    code: "type2",
    order: 3
  },
  {
    Id: 2,
    name: 'sample 4',
    code: "type3",
    order: 4
  },

  {
    Id: 3,
    name: 'sample 1',
    code: "type",
    order: 1
  },
  {
    Id: 3,
    name: 'sample 2',
    code: "type1",
    order: 2
  },
  {
    Id: 3,
    name: 'sample 3',
    code: "type2",
    order: 3
  },

  {
    Id: 4,
    name: 'sample 1',
    code: "type",
    order: 1
  },
  {
    Id: 4,
    name: 'sample 2',
    code: "type1",
    order: 2
  },
  {
    Id: 4,
    name: 'sample 3',
    code: "type2",
    order: 3
  }
];

let newData = data.filter(item => item.Id === 2 && item.name === 'sample 4');
console.log(newData)
```